# How to make wordpress run locally

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress.
I just downloaded a wordpress installation from a hosting.

I have copied that installation on my laptop.
But when I tried to open it (localhost/my-wordpress), it always open the online version (http://www.my-wordpress.com.

How to make the local installation run locally?

Answer (score 0):

try typing localhost/my-wordpress/wp-admin.php

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer:

there is one additional script (not from wordpress installation) that redirects to the online version.

And I also changed the value of option_value in wp_options table for option_name 'home' and 'siteurl'.

Answer (score 0):

You should go to your database (through phpmyadmin or any other software), go the table "wp_options", find the row where option_name is "siteurl" and change it to "localhost/my-wordpress".